# Submitting a form using JavaScript using narrow scopes to avoid conflicts

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using the javascript below to submit a form that has an id of PrimaryCatForm as it forms far cleaner and it avoid code conflicts.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#PrimaryCatForm').on('change', function(){
     this.submit()
});
    });
//onChange="document.getElementById(\'PrimaryCatForm\').submit();"
</script>

<head>
```

The form doesn't seem get submitted.

HTML form

```
<form id="PrimaryCatForm" name="PrimaryCatForm" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: onChange doesn't fire on form elements. What kind of event are you trying to capture?

Comment: Are you trying to submit a form on any inner input change?

Comment: you need to do `this.submit()`

Comment: @mplungjan - I tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

`submit()` is a JS/jQuery method, not a standalone function (unless you defined it), so you need to call it "on" something:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#PrimaryCatForm').on('change', function(){
    $(this).submit();
  });
});
```

See it here:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#PrimaryCatForm').on('change', function() {
        $(this).submit();
      });
    });
 
    // ignore this part, 
    // this is just to prevent submitting in the snippet here
    $('#PrimaryCatForm').on('submit', function() {
      alert('calling form submit!');
      return false; // prevent actual submitting
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="PrimaryCatForm" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```

---

Note: if you wish to submit the form on every change (every character typed/deleted, for example), you should consider listeners other than `onchange` (which triggers when the field loses focus), like `onkeyup` which will fire on each de-pressed key.

Answer (score 1):

A form element does not have an 'on change' event, only its input fields:

```
var form = $("#PrimaryCatForm");

form.filter(':input').on("change", function() {
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Why do you expect there would be more than one elements with the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

`this.submit()` does work.

```js
    $(function(){ 
        $("#form1").change(function() {
           console.log('A value in form has been changed');
            this.submit();
        });
    })
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="test"/>
</form>
```

Comment: But `$("form").change(//..)` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer for the sake of completeness just to explain that you **can** actually bind to `onchange` event on the form, because of Event bubbling.

However your code is a little confusing, because form elements don't have `onchnage` events, but even though it will still work due to the fact that `onchange` events bubble up to the form from inner form elements. In this case all you need to do is to use `this` form reference and invoke it's submit method:

```
$('#PrimaryCatForm').on('change', function() {
     $(this).submit(); // or this.submit();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dqo04o12/

Comment: It does, but only after unselecting the input field

Comment: Of course, this is how onchange events work on inputs, you need to blur the field to trigger it.

Comment: @mplungjan Not really. The purpose of my answer is some explanations on `onchange` event behavior in regards to form element.